# Script validation a number 1-100

Tags: javascript, regex

So I need to write a script that validates a number that is great than zero and less than 100. The catch is that the number can only be accepted if there is decimal in the middle position and has at least two decimal places.

Examples: `19.30` would validate but `9.3`, `9.30`, and `19.3` would be considered invalid.

I'm thinking a regular expressions would be the best way to validate the decimal criteria?

Comment: Is the number a number or a string?

Comment: @kfedorov91 a number it would be a prompt box most likely where I would be using the script.

Comment: @akcode17 But a prompt box returns a string

Comment: @JBDouble05 my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Comments in the code:

```js
function validNumber(string) {
  // parse string into number
  let number = parseFloat(string, 10);
  // check if number is in range
  if (number <= 0 || number >= 100) return false;
  // check if number is formatted correctly
  if (string !== number.toFixed(2)) return false;
  // return true if all conditions pass
  return true;
}

console.log(validNumber("19.30")); // true
console.log(validNumber("9.3")); // false
console.log(validNumber("19.3")); // false
console.log(validNumber("100.30")); // false
console.log(validNumber("1.00")); // true
```

Comment: Would this look different without converting to a number and keeping it string?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is split on the decimal, then the test the lengths of the strings.

```js
function validate(number) {
  let [whole, decimal] = number.toString().split('.', 2)
  let int = parseInt(whole)
  return whole.length == decimal.length && decimal.length >= 2 
    && int > 0 && int < 100
}

console.log(validate('19.30'))
console.log(validate('9.3'))
console.log(validate('9.30'))
console.log(validate('-9.30'))
console.log(validate('19.3'))
console.log(validate('99.99'))
console.log(validate('1.111'))
console.log(validate('100.111'))
console.log(validate('1000.111'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regex meets your needs I think provided input is string along with comparison operator

```
\d{1,3}\.\d{2}+
```

You could use it as following:

```
const isValid = (input) => {
  const num = parseFloat(input, 10);
  return (!!input.match(/\d{1,3}\.\d{2}+/) && num > 0 && num < 100);
};

isValid('19.3') // => false
isValid('19.30') // => true
```

Comment: 1) Does not satisfy the "*has at least two decimal places*" part, for example, it does not match `1.111`. 2) Does not satisfy the "*greater than zero and less than 100*" part, for example it matches `0.00`.

Comment: both of the issues fixed I think

Comment: You can also do everything in a single efficient regex: `(0*[1-9][0-9]?\.[0-9]{2}[0-9]*)|(0+\.(0[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9]0[0-9]*|000*[1-9][0-9]*))` ([diagram](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NmeqzZZePipa_GAy))